# What is the pun of "If I could keep my Gmail account, I’d be okay with that."

Tags: expressions, pun

The following is from the sitcom "The Big Bang Theory"

> Leonard: My point is, immortality is not only a possibility, it is
>   real.
>
> Raj: Only if you’re this jellyfish which periodically reverts to a
>   mass of undifferentiated protoplasm.
>
> Sheldon: If I could keep my Gmail account, I’d be okay with that.

I was just wondering what is humorous in the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bathos.  A contrast between serious and casual.

> Serious: You can live forever but you have to lose all traces of your personality and become a lump of jelly, then regenerate into a new form.
>
> Casual: Ok, but can I still use the same email address.

It is funny because if you are turning into jelly then your first worry is usually not your email provider.

There is no pun. A pun is joke which uses the fact that some words have multiple meanings. "A boiled egg every morning is *hard to beat*."

Answer (score 0):

Sheldon so identifies with his Gmail account that he would not mind being reduced to undifferentiated protoplasm if he could keep the account. The statement underlines the abnormal importance he attaches to Gmail.